# Submitting Modal to php(ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, submit

I'm having problems in submitting my Modal form to my php page. This is my first time learning ajax and I'm having troubles with it with my webpage. I dont have a problem in fetching my data to my modal. The only thing that I'm having trouble with is the **Update**.  I'm using PDO for my database.

Here's my **modal code:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Special Sales</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="update_form">  
                        <label for="bulk">Bulk/Wholesale:</label>
                     <input type="number" class="form-control textboxsize"  value="0.00"  id="bulk" name="bulk">
                          <br />  
                          <label for="offsite">OFFSITE:</label>
                     <input type="number" class="form-control textboxsize"  value="0.00"  id="offsite" name="offsite">
                          <br /> 
                         <label for="cater">CATERING:</label>
                     <input type="number" class="form-control textboxsize"  value="0.00"  id="cater" name="cater">
                          <br /> 
                            <label for="others">OTHERS:</label>
                     <input type="number" class="form-control textboxsize"  value="0.00"  id="others" name="others">
                          <br />   
                          <input type="hidden" name="table_id" id="table_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="UPDATE" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
</div>
```

Here's my AJAX:

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           $('#update').val("update");  
           $('#update_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
           var table_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"fetchdata.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{table_id:table_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#bulk').val(data.BULK);  

                     $('#table_id').val(data.ID);  
                     $('#update').val("UPDATE");  
                     $('#myModal').modal('show');  
                }  
           });  
      });  
      $('#update_form').on("submit", function(){  
          // event.preventDefault();   
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"update.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#update_form').serialize(),  
                     beforeSend:function(){  
                          $('#update').val("UPDATING");  
                     },  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#update_form')[0].reset();  
                          $('#myModal').modal('hide');  
                          $('#record_table').html(data);  
                     }  
                });  

      });  

 });  
 </script>
```

Here's my **php code for update.php:**

```
include 'dbconn/database.php';

$bulk = $_POST["bulk"];
$offsite = $_POST["offsite"];
$cater = $_POST["cater"];
$others = $_POST["others"];

$id = $_POST["table_id"];

$query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE sales set BULK = '$bulk' where ID = $id");
$query->execute();
```

Comment: What is the behavior? If you alert the `data` in the success callback what you will see? Or any error in browser console?

Comment: @UserProg No errors. It just lets me go back to my index without any update on my data.

Comment: Please `echo` all the variables in `update.php` and also the query to make sure you are receiving all the values correctly and the query is right. If you echo, I expect you will see the value if you do `alert(data);` in the success callback

Comment: @UserProg I've already echoed the variables in my PHP and it just redirects me to my index.php I've also added exit(); function as well but somehow it didnt redirect there? weird.

Comment: Not sure why the redirect is taking place as I don't see any redirect in your code. Try to do some alerts in your code and try to trace the flow. See where it redirects.

Comment: Please change this ` $('#update_form').on("submit", function(){  `  
 as `  $('#update_form').on("submit", function(event){  ` and uncomment this line     event.preventDefault();

Comment: @Mahesh I've uncomment the event.preventDefault and added the event code. Unfortunately, it only change my button to UPDATING then nothing happens.

Comment: Is your modal window in the index page as well?